# How do I get readable system information at the command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, system-information, system-profiler

I'm using High Sierra. I often have to copy & paste system information in a email or in a forum message. For this reason, I'd like a simple and easy way to get info on my operating system and my hardware at the command line. Currently I use

```
$ system_profiler > foo.txt
```

and then I search into `foo.txt` for the information I need. However, the process is *incredibly* slow, and not very automatic. Is there a better way? I only need OS, SDD/RAM & chipset info - I couldn't care less about sound or Firewalls, for example.

Comment: You can check data types by listing them with `system_profiler -listDataTypes` and then use them to get specific info. For example to get info about SDD, you run `system_profiler SPSerialATADataType`

Comment: _very_ interesting, but  `system_profiler SPSerialATADataType` doesn't return anything on my Mac. Are you sure this is the SDD info?

Comment: It works on mine. Please check other data types to find what you need.

Comment: `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` gives me chipset & RAM info, and `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` gives me OS info. It's weird I can't get SDD info, but that's the least important of the three. If you write an answer like `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType SPSoftwareDataType > foo.txt` I'll accept it, otherwise I'll write one myself and accept my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check data types by listing them with `system_profiler -listDataTypes` and then use them to get specific info. For example to get info about chipset & RAM run `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType`.